# Changes beyond Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I update some data beyond EF (in sql management tools for example) at runtime I can't get those changes by calling

```
entities_name.table_name
```

Only changes made in that "session" are refreshing. How to deal with it?

Comment: What code do you run exactly?

Comment: And do you mean a daily build of EF7 (beyond ef6) https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide more detail on how exactly you are accessing your data.

There are a couple of ways you can access data in EF. This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx) may help.

**Local**

```
context.Blogs.Local.ToList()
```

**Remote**

```
context.Blogs.ToList()
```

Comment: I access data in second way: context.Blogs.ToList() . Despite that data which is changed beyond EF don't update in EF when I call context.Blogs.ToList() again.

Comment: Well then the data should be updated. Try creating a new context to test the issue. `new MyDbContext().Blogs.ToList()` With a new context you should get the latest data each time.